# Not showing json parsed data in an unordered list

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have the following json file which I want to show as a list.

```
[
{
"shopName": "The Coffee Connection",
"address": "123 Lakeside Way",
"phone": "16503600708",
"prices": [
  {
    "Cafe Latte": 4.75,
    "Flat White": 4.75,
    "Cappucino": 3.85,
    "Single Espresso": 2.05,
    "Double Espresso": 3.75,
    "Americano": 3.75,
    "Cortado": 4.55,
    "Tea": 3.65,
    "Choc Mudcake": 6.40,
    "Choc Mousse": 8.20,
    "Affogato": 14.80,
    "Tiramisu": 11.40,
    "Blueberry Muffin": 4.05,
    "Chocolate Chip Muffin": 4.05,
    "Muffin Of The Day": 4.55
    }
  ]
 }
]
```

I want to iterate over the prices and show them in in a listView.  I am using the the following Ajax function and function to extract this data.  Unfortunately when I run my code I have an empty list.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '/data/hipstercoffee.json',
success: function(data) {
  // console.log('success', data);
  let widget = show(data);
  $("#Meals").html(widget);
}

});
```

and my other function is.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '/data/hipstercoffee.json',
dataType:'json',
success: function(data) {
  var data = JSON.parse(data)[0];
  // console.log('success', data);
  let widget = show(data);
  $("#Meals").html(widget);
 }

});
```

I am getting unexpected o at JSON at position 1 error.

Comment: data seems to be an array with a single object instead of just an object

Comment: I see that it is a single object and does not have a key valued pair.  What would be the best way to iterate over this.

Comment: what was the result of `console.log('success', data);`?

Comment: the best way would be to either restructure your data object or get array index 0 from data and prices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `prices` is an array with a single element (object). So you need to process this object. Something like this.

```js
var data = [{
  "shopName": "The Coffee Connection",
  "address": "123 Lakeside Way",
  "phone": "16503600708",
  "prices": [{
    "Cafe Latte": 4.75,
    "Flat White": 4.75,
    "Cappucino": 3.85,
    "Single Espresso": 2.05,
    "Double Espresso": 3.75,
    "Americano": 3.75,
    "Cortado": 4.55,
    "Tea": 3.65,
    "Choc Mudcake": 6.40,
    "Choc Mousse": 8.20,
    "Affogato": 14.80,
    "Tiramisu": 11.40,
    "Blueberry Muffin": 4.05,
    "Chocolate Chip Muffin": 4.05,
    "Muffin Of The Day": 4.55
  }]
}];

function show(data) {
  var ul = '<ul>' +
    Object.keys(data[0].prices[0]).map(function(key) {
      return '<li>' + key + ': ' + data[0].prices[0][key] + '</li>';
    }).join('') +
    '</ul>';
  $('#result').html(ul);
}
show(data); //for demonstration purpose
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="result">loading...</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a string. You have to decode the it first to turn it into a javascript object. Also notice that an array [] is wrapped around the actual data object.

```
var data = JSON.parse(data)[0];
```

Tip: When retrieving data, always output it first (console.log(data)) in your success message, to see how the data is structured. You will spot things like the array much faster that way. Once your code is working, remove the output.

Comment: Would this go into the function(data)  Beppe?

Comment: Yes, you can decode directly in the success function:  var data = JSON.parse(data)[0];

Comment: Does it work? Unfortunately you overwrote the show function, so I can not see if there was maybe also a mistake.